# Rails 3 Kaminari fallback to first page if current page is out_of_range

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari, fallback

I want to fallback to page 1 if the page number provided is `out_of_range?`.

For example if there are total 10 records and per_page is 5 which makes two pages. I want to fall back to page 1 if someone tries to hit page 3 which doesn't exist.

We are using `kaminari (0.16.1)`.

Comment: If the page is not there it should be shown as blank right? The user might think it as page 3 data.

Comment: I am not familiar with Kaminari but how would that even happen?  At least when I've implemented paging, there is no option to navigate to a non-existent page.  Even if a user modifies the URL to reference a non-existent page, he should just see paging controls with no data.